# Visual Studio for Mac crashes every time I try to sign in

Tags: visual-studio-mac

A few months ago I couldn't open VS for Mac. Today I followed the instructions from https://superuser.com/a/1208658/815258 and that help me to code again, but when I try to sign in I got the following message:

[image: Error message]

In the "more information" button I got this:

```
{
    "payload" : 
{
  "protocol_version" : "0.0.2",
  "configuration" : {
    "version" : "5.16.0.238 (2018-06/99d74f7f6ee)",
    "tlc" : "normal",
    "sigsgev" : "altstack",
    "notifications" : "kqueue",
    "architecture" : "amd64",
    "disabled_features" : "none",
    "smallconfig" : "disabled",
    "bigarrays" : "disabled",
    "softdebug" : "enabled",
    "interpreter" : "enabled"
  },
  "memory" : {
    "Resident Size" : "301850624",
    "Virtual Size" : "6042132480",
    "minor_gc_time" : "805247",
    "major_gc_time" : "112614",
    "minor_gc_count" : "18",
    "major_gc_count" : "1",
    "major_gc_time_concurrent" : "1503533"
 },
  "threads" : [
 {
    "is_managed" : false,
    "crashed" : true,
    "managed_thread_ptr" : "0x0",
    "native_thread_id" : "0x0",
    "thread_info_addr" : "0x0",
    "managed_exception_type" : "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException"
  }
  ]
},
    "parameters" : 
{
        "ApplicationBundleId" : "com.microsoft.visual-studio",
        "ApplicationVersion" : "7.8.3.2",
        "ApplicationBitness" : "x64",
        "ApplicationName" : "Visual Studio",
        "BlameModuleName" : "Mono Exception",
        "BlameModuleVersion" : "5.16.0.238 (2018-06/99d74f7f6ee)",
        "BlameModuleOffset" : "0x0",
        "ExceptionType" : "0x02000000",
        "StackChecksum" : "0x0",
        "StackHash" : "0x0",
        "OSVersion" : "17.7.0",
        "LanguageID" : "0x7f",
        "SystemManufacturer" : "apple",
        "SystemModel" : "MacBookPro9,2",
        "EventType" : "AppleAppCrash"
    }
}
```

I tried to restart the machine and to simple shutdown and turned on later but the problem persists.

EDIT:
The IDE log is in https://pastebin.com/3WbAfT9G

Comment: Might sound like a pain, but have you tried uninstall and reinstall it fresh again?

Comment: Can you post any errors from the IDE log? (Help - Open Log Directory). The information posted does not really indicate what the error is. The only problem I know about that can cause a crash on signing in is if you have an old TFS extension installed. If that is the case updating it using the Extensions Manager, or uninstalling it, and restarting Visual Studio for Mac should solve that problem.

Comment: @MattWard, please go to https://pastebin.com/3WbAfT9G, I uploaded the log from today.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no crash information in the IDE log. However in the IDE log I can see that you have the MonoDevelop.VersionControl.TFS extension installed. I would try updating that using the Extensions Manager, or uninstalling it, and then restarting Visual Studio for Mac.